# Scrapy: how to deploy more than one projects?

Tags: scrapy

My scrapy.cfg is:

```
[settings]
default = project1.settings

[deploy:project1]
url = http://localhost:7000/
project = project1
version = dev

[deploy:project2]
url = http://localhost:7000/
project = project2
version = dev
```

And my directory structure is:

> projects
>
> --project1
>
> ----spiders
>
> --project2
>
> ----spiders
>
> --scrapy.cfg

How to modify the [settings] section to deploy project2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 2 projects (project1 and project2):

```
[settings]
default = project1.settings
project2 = project2.settings
```

Pass the `SCRAPY_PROJECT` environment variable to `scrapy` command:

```
$ SCRAPY_PROJECT=project2 scrapy deploy project2
```

Note: make sure that root directory is clean (remove `setup.py`, `build`, etc) before running it.